# System says I flagged as "not welcome", but I didn't

Tags: bug, flags

I flagged a question as spam, and wanted to add a second, custom flag to let moderators and developers know about a repeating pattern I was seeing. When I clicked the flag link to add the second flag, I got this dialog:

[image]

It says that I already raised both a *spam* flag and a *not welcome* flag, but that's not true; I just raised one flag, a *spam* flag. It probably does make sense to disable both options when either type of flag was already raised, but the messages stating that I raised two flags are wrong and confusing.